# Dynamically change class of drop down items in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, angular-material-5

If the first part of selected element (before "*" character) match with first part of drop down element (before "*" character), the class will not change the font color, if not match then class will fire and font color will change.

Logic needs to make dynamically enable disable element, if first part of name will not match with first part of selected element.

Here is my array of object which producing drop down using angular material mat select.

```
emp[
    {"id":1001,"name":"robin_010"},
    {"id":1002,"name":"robin_020"},
    {"id":1003,"name":"robin_030"},
    {"id":1004,"name":"sushil_040"},
    {"id":1005,"name":"sushil_050"},
]
```

Here is my html template code to display drop down using mat select

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select [(value)]="sel (change)="hideEmp()" [formControl]="toppings" 
multiple required>
<mat-option [class.hiddenpro]="is_hide" *ngFor="let p of emp;
 [value]="p" >{{p.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In my CSS, I added the class

```
.hiddenpro
{
    color: #ddd !important;
}
```

Here is my .ts file, I have implemented the hideProjects()

```
        hideEmp()
            {

       /* sel is selected object, getting from  drop down, once selected,
 to get the name property from the object, looping through for each.
    */ 

                if(this.sel && this.sel.length){
                var proc="";
                this.sel.forEach(res=>{
                proc+=res.name + " ";   // proc containing the name
                })
                }

    // Get the first part of name property in var procd (before "_")

                var procd=proc.substring(0, proc.indexOf("_"));

    //Looping emp data to compare all the values through var procd

                for(let i=0; i<this.emp.length; i++){

    //hdata containing the first part of elements  (before "_")

                var hdata=this.emp[i].name.substring(0, this.nproj[i].name.indexOf("_"));

    //comparing selected element with drop down data

                if(procd==hdata)
                {
                this.is_hide =false;  // hiddenpro will not work
                }
                else
                {
                this.is_hide =true;  //hiddenpro will work
                }
             }
            }
```

If some one select the first element, the last two element color will be changed.

This code is not working properly, kindly help

Or any better way to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your select change function is hideEmp() and you are trying to trigger hideProjects() ?

```
<mat-option [class.hiddenpro]="is_hide" *ngFor="let p of nproj;
 let i = index;" [value]="i" >{{p.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

dont mix the index with other variables.

where are you calling hideProjects() in the component.html ?

Comment: it was typo, I have updated the question, kindly advice, class is applying for all the elements.

Comment: Also I have updated the index variable, still facing same issue. Any better way to do this.

Comment: what is nproj ?

Comment: nproj contains data of emp

Comment: can you recheck the whole logic, i found some confusions

Comment: if(this.emp && this.emp.length){
        var proc="";
        this.emp.forEach(res=>{
        proc+=res.name + " ";
        })
        }

we are getting a single value for emp ( <mat-select [(ngModel)]="emp" ), then why using forEach loop; dont mix variables.  reacheck all variables and datas

Comment: sel is not array, then why are you using foreach for that variabl e?

Comment: sel is object, its having id and name of selected element, I am accessing the  name here  {"id":1001,"name":"robin_010"}

Comment: any better way to do this, kindly suggest

Comment: @mjck, you need to add class to selected options, right ?. if not what are you trying to achieve

Comment: If not no class will be added, it will return false.

Comment: there is lot of bug in you code, can you reproduce in fiddler like thing

Comment: can I achieve this using custom pipe

Comment: the logic you need and the logic implemented is different, i dont know hoe to make a example like fiddler, if i can i will send you link to fiddler or similar